# can not type anything in blank screen when using telnet in cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, telnet

i have a problem with telnet in cmd.
i write this command in cmd:

```
telnet cis.poly.edu 80
```

then i hit enter twice.
at this time a blank screen appears but i can not type anything in this window.
if i type anything and then hit enter, 400 bad request error will be appeared.
at this time i want to write

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: cis.poly.edu
```

but i can not write anything. even the cursor does not move when i type.

Comment: What happens if you type what you want to type - your GET request - without seeing it? (I have tested locally with telnet and get a 200 response, FWIW)

Comment: when i press any key at this time,  it gets back to the cmd prompt. sometimes when i type anything and before it goes back to cmd prompt, i hit enter, 400 bad request appears.

Comment: why can not i write anything in this blank screen?

Comment: Are you specifying 80 and is this correct?  Normally telnet uses 23.

Comment: yes it is correct. its my book's practice.

Comment: Your book should mention that you need to be in "old line mode" and need to set "local echo" on by typing a single CTRL+E.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. Apparently, you are still able to write even though you dont see what you are writing. If you type in everything correctly and then push enter enter, you will see the desired data

Comment: @Destroy666 yes it does. It's absolutely correct

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do same thing.

At first, I used telnet on Windows system and tried to follow Hannu's answer (set "old line mode" and set "local echo") by using these commands but still not work, unable to type GET message into it:

```
Set mode stream
Set localecho
```

So, I switch to use telnet on Ubuntu system and it just works.

[image]